# Use manually added SDL2 with steamcmd.sh | CentOS 8

Tags: centos, environment-variables, path, make

I installed the `steamcmd` and I got the following error:

`Steam>Warning: failed to init SDL thread priority manager: SDL not found`

Because `CentOS8 centos-release-8.2-2.2004.0.1.el8.x86_64` only comes with `SDL1.2` but
`steamcmd` is relying on `SDL2`

So I followed a instruction to compile and make `SDL2`

```
1. SDL2-2.0.12.tar.gz extracted
2. ./configure
3. make all
4. make install
```

> Note: If you do a manual install you may have to specify where the
> headers and library files are for your compiler/IDE.

How do I specify where the headers and library files are so my `steamcmd.sh` can use it?
Because it is still printing `Steam>Warning: failed to init SDL thread priority manager: SDL not found` after the installation.

Comment: Some steamuser:
_You can ignore this error message. The update will still run without problems. If you have problems starting your server, look here: https://steamcommunity.com/app/346110/discussions/0/1751275687421356824/_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDL2 is in the "PowerTools" repository, which is included but disabled in CentOS 8.

Just enable it with:

```
sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled PowerTools
sudo dnf install SDL2.i686
```

You probably want to have [EPEL8](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) installed too.
[**EDIT**: Added i686 package]

Comment: hmmm I still get `Steam>Warning: failed to init SDL thread priority manager: SDL not found`

Comment: You probably need SDL2.i686, since Steam is 32-bit.

Comment: this did the trick, thank you very much
maybe you want to edit your answer and add the 32bit part